# Dont see any Yahoo Logout API or Javascript or URL to use in our application

Tags: yahoo-oauth

I have integrated Login with Yahoo in our application using Oauth2.0 authorization code flow which is working fine. Once user is login using this option and user profile information extracted, I want to logout user from Yahoo as user is not aware that they have Yahoo session active. I dont not see any Yahoo Logout API or Javascript or URL to use in our application. Yahoo logout URL is not unique and needs crumb value for each logout in the url.

https://login.yahoo.com/config/login/?logout_all=1&.crumb=yQBVhxADZpA&.direct=2&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com

Please let me know if there is any standard Yahoo logout approach.